# WinDBG - Analyse dump file on local PC

Tags: asp.net, debugging, windbg

I have created a memory dump of an ASP.NET process on a server using the following command: .dump /ma mydump.dmp.  I am trying to identify a memory leak.

I want to look at the dump file in more detail on my local development PC.  I read somewhere that it is advisable to debug on the same machine as you create the dump file.  However, I have also read that some developers do analyse the dump file on their local development PC's.  What is the best approach?

I notice that when I create a dump file using the command above the W3WP process memory increases by about 1.5 times.  Why this this? I suppose this should be avoided on a live server.

Comment: @EdChum, could I ask you to read this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87767/accept-an-answer-obligation. I regularly go back to through my questions to mark them awswered. I will only mark a question as answered if I am confident that it has helped me. If I just mark any question as answered then other users may be mislead when they read the question and answer in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analyzing on the same machine can save you from SOS loading issues thereafter. Unless you are familiar with WinDbg and SOS, you will find it confusing and frustrating then.

If you have to use another machine for analysis, make sure you read carefully this blog post, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dougste/archive/2009/02/18/failed-to-load-data-access-dll-0x80004005-or-what-is-mscordacwks-dll.aspx as it shows you how to copy the necessary files from the source machine (where the dump is captured) to the target machine (the one you launch WinDbg).

For your second question, as you use WinDbg to attach to the process directly, and use .dump command to capture the dump, the target process unfortunately is modified. Not easy to explain in a few words. The recommended way is to use ADPlus.exe or Debug Diag. Even procdump from SysInternals is better. Those tools are designed for dump capture and they have minimal impact on the target processes.

For memory leak from unmanaged libraries, you should use memory leak rule of Debug Diag. for managed memory leak, you can simply capture hang dumps when memory usage is high.

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert on WinDBG but I once had to analyse a dump file on my ASP.NET site to find a `StackOverflowException`.

While I got a dump file of my live site (I had no choice since that was what was failing), originally I tried to analyse that dump file on my local dev PC but ran into problems when trying to load the CLR data from it. The reason being that the exact version of the .NET framework differed between my dev PC and the server - both were .NET 4 but I imagine my dev PC had some cumulative updates installed that the server did not. The [SOS module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) simply refused to load because of this discrepancy. I actually wrote a [blog post](http://inthecodingzone.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/how-windbg-helped-me-find-my.html) about my findings.

So to answer part of your question it may be that you have no choice but to run WinDBG from your server, at least you can be sure that the dump file will match your environment.

Comment: Thanks.  I suppose you did this out of core hours?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not have that luxury! I was getting `StackOverflowExceptions` every 30 minutes so had to track it down ASAP. From what I recall though attaching to the w3wp.exe process didn't cause much performance issues on the site as far as I could tell, but that is your call.

Comment: Thanks.  Are you able to answer the second part of my question? The ASP.NET process memory increases by about 1.5 times when I create a dump file.  Why is this? I am new to WinDBG.

Comment: That I can't explain, like I said I'm no expert and only figured out enough to fix my problem. My best guess would be that if the debugger is attaching to the process then it will simply consume more memory but I'm sure someone more knowledgeable could explain it better

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to debug on the actual machine unless the problem is difficult to manifest on your development machine.

So long as you have the pdbs with the private symbols then the symbols should be resolved and call stacks correctly displayed and the correct version of .NET installed.

In terms of looking at memory leaks you should enable Gflags user stack trace and take memory dumps at 2 intervals so you can compare the memory usage before and after the action that provokes the memory leak, remember to disable gflags afterwards!

You could also run DebugDiag on the server which has automated memory pressure analysis scripts that will work with .Net leaks.